# Hadoop Beginner - Data Ingestion & Analysis

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

HDFS stores both structured & unstructured data.HIVE & IMPALA enables us to write sql queries which are then converted to MapReduce. How the user comes to know about the schema in which data is stored or how those tables are formed from data stored In HDFS?

Comment: You can read data through sql only if you have previously defined metadata on Hive. This metadata explain the schema of data. See reference for create table on hive.

Comment: desc formatted table_name; -> gives the details of how the table details and 
show create table table_name; gives how the table is created.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Parquet file format, there are tools for inspecting the file block directly. See [this](https://github.com/rdblue/parquet-cli) for instance. And most of the hadoop file formats have similar handy tools too, such as https://orc.apache.org/docs/tools.html for orcfiles.